# iOS application transition to 64-bit architecture

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, xcode

I have project with a lot of libraries. Some of them are binaries and some are in sources (in c and c++). I wonder if I should do some additional steps to build an application for 64 bit architecture. Or I just have to verify if they work OK with new type sizes?

Comment: If your binaries are not built with a 64-bit slice, you will not be able to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you are compiling your C and C++ files that you are ***targeting 64-bit platforms***. 
If you are compiling in Visual Studio for instance, you can use the information  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx)  to ensure your solution platform is 64-bit. Besides that, so long as your binaries are all 64-bit you should be fine.